# running pg_dump with the context of a user

Tags: permissions, user-permissions

```
$ whomi
admin

$ pg_dump
(it works....)

$ sudo pg_dump
doesn't work. (permission denied)

$ sudo -u admin pg_dump 
still doesn't work (permission denied).
```

why is that?

I need to run pg_dump from the context of being the user "www-data". How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show us the full error messages please.

Answer (score 1):

Your system user `admin` has a matching PostgreSQL account called `admin`, and the `pg_hba.conf` rules allow it to authenticate. If you want PostgreSQL to also support users `root` or `www-data`, create them in PostgreSQL, and set up equivalent rules for them, too.

Comment: where is the "admin" account in postgres? I don't see it. when I do "\du" there is no admin on the list.

Comment: There is no such account by default, you can create it the normal way users are created in PostgreSQL. (Typically the `postgres` account is the administrative account.)